# What's the affect on a ReplicaSet when deleting millions of documents by query?

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, mongodb-query

I have a collection that has more than 8.2 million documents.  I need to remove 2-3 million of them by query (the attribute or two attributes are indexed).

My concern is causing my secondaries fall behind by having the oplog grow larger than I have capacity for and then needing me to re-seed them all from backups.

Would something like this...

```
db.my_collection.remove({attribute_1:'xyz'},false);
```

or

```
db.my_collection.remove({attribute_1:'xyz',attribute_2:'abc'},false);
```

be a single oplog entry that would not have a negative impact on my secondaries (besides actually removing the documents)? Or would it be translated to 2-3 million operations for replication?

I think the answer is that it would be one operation and I'd have some fragmentation that I might need to recover from, but not necessarily an oplog/secondary sync issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would end up with an individual entry in the oplog for every document that is removed on the primary.

So, if you had 3 million documents removed on the primary, you would end up with 3 million remove statements via the _id key on the secondaries.

I would batch them and throttle the deletes based on the lag, and then compact or resync afterwards.

If you have a lot of document movement, you will probably want to consider compacting with the paddingFactor set.

Comment: If I wanted to script such a thing, is there something better you're aware of than trying to parse the output of db.printReplicationInfo() or db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()?

Comment: If you're scripting it, I would use the underlying replSetGetStatus command.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy enough to test this by creating a collection and adding a few matching documents to `remove()`.

You can then inspect the oplog to see what entries are generated:

```
use local
db.oplog.rs.find({op:'d'})
```

In order to ensure the same documents are deleted on the primary and secondaries, each document removed generates an entry in the oplog.

For example, deleted entries in oplog (`op: 'd'`) after a `remove()` matching two documents:

```
{
    "ts" : Timestamp(1379971718, 1),
    "h" : NumberLong("8227301495520897544"),
    "v" : 2,
    "op" : "d",
    "ns" : "test.foo",
    "b" : true,
    "o" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5240b21e2fa8b603e8aaaceb")
    }
}
{
    "ts" : Timestamp(1379971718, 2),
    "h" : NumberLong("-5339031341149346886"),
    "v" : 2,
    "op" : "d",
    "ns" : "test.foo",
    "b" : true,
    "o" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5240b2202fa8b603e8aaacec")
    }
}
```

Comment: That's clear enough.  Is there a recommended best practice from MongoDB on this?

Comment: If you are concerned about the impact on replication lag jeffl's approach of batching & throttling deletions is very sensible. Without knowing more resource/performance details of your server environment it is hard to say what the impact of the deletions will be (i.e. your secondaries may be able to keep up fine). The [default oplog size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/#oplog-size) for 64-bit Linux systems is 5% of free disk space, so unless you have a small oplog you are probably unlikely to roll it over with a few million deletes. Best to test in staging/QA environment